# Android Emulator - Unexpected '-prop' value

Tags: android, android-emulator, visual-studio-mac

I've seen this error plenty enough but not on a 2020 Macbook pro with an Apple M1 chip, running through Visual Studio 2019 for Mac.

When I try to start the Android emulator, I get an error; "Unexpected error"

When I go into the Android Device Manager through Visual Studio, the options are limited but, attempting to start the emulator gives the well known

> Device error: WARNING: unexpected '-prop' value ('monodroid.avdname=pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28'), only 'qemu.' properties are supported WARNING: unexpected '-prop' value ('emu.uuid=7698980f-2d31-4db3-973b-df409a67754d'), only 'qemu.' properties are supported

Viewing the log for this, it ends with the following (formatted as code to maintain line breaks):

```
[2021-05-10 18:39:15.0] 
emulator: registered 'boot-properties' qemud service
[2021-05-10 18:39:15.0] 
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.cmdline' = 'androidboot.logcat=v:* androidboot.consolepipe=qemu_pipe,pipe:logcat'
[2021-05-10 18:39:15.0] 
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.logcat' = 'start'
[2021-05-10 18:39:15.0] 
emulator: CPU Acceleration: DISABLED
[2021-05-10 18:39:15.0] 
emulator: CPU Acceleration status: Android Emulator requires an Intel processor with VT-x and NX support.  (VT-x is not supported)
[2021-05-10 18:39:15.0] 
emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
[2021-05-10 18:39:15.0] 
CPU acceleration status: Android Emulator requires an Intel processor with VT-x and NX support.  (VT-x is not supported)
[2021-05-10 18:39:15.0] 
More info on configuring VM acceleration on macOS:
[2021-05-10 18:39:15.0] 
https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration#vm-mac
[2021-05-10 18:39:15.0] 
General information on acceleration: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration.
[2021-05-10 18:39:15.0] 

[2021-05-10 18:39:15.0]
```

Following guides, like [this one](https://guides.codepath.com/android/installing-android-sdk-tools), or trying to follow [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager) seems impossible.

I'm not sure where to begin in getting this to work; it works fine on my old iMac

Thanks!

Comment: I was getting this error with my AMD Ryzen 3 1200 as well.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Android are working on an update to the emulator that supports the M1 chip

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Android device manager is not working in VS 2019 with M1 chipset in Macbook Pro because of M1's ARM Architecture. You can try to create one emulator with arm64-v8a in android Device manager in VS, it will not throw any exception but will show only a blank screen.
So there are **2 ways** to do it. For a **permanent** fix > install Android studio and in its >Device Manager, in >other's tab , install arm64-v8a based emulator image and it will work fine (try 2-3 emulators if does not work in one go) and other fix is **temporary**, for which you can follow link:https://medium.com/techiepedia/setting-up-android-emulator-in-m1-mac-fff58ec8bff8 and download link (Initial preview 3) is : https://github.com/google/android-emulator-m1-preview/releases.
Few known issues are there, but for basic debugging you can use it.